# Can’t understand what this shader is doing

Tags: shaders, glsl

I believe this is a fragment shader which is supposed to distort an image by creating a zoom and swirl like affect but I have no idea what the shader is actually doing

```
#version 330 
in vec2 v_tex;
out vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform float u_amount;
void main()
{
    vec2 center = vec2(0.5, 0.5); 
    Vec2 displacement = normalize(v_tex - center)*u_amount;
    color = texture(u_texture, v_tex - displacement);

}
```

What is v_tex ? Where is this vec2 coming from?

What is sampler2D u_texture? Does this use a default texture or is it being passed in?

I understand uniform float u_amount I believe that has to be passed on as the distortion amount?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. If you have an example shader doing this thing that you want clarified, include it in your question.

Comment: @DMGregory I have revised my question

Comment: NOO I WAS WRITING A FULL EXPLANATION hahahahaha

I sent it anyway since I think it could still help answering your revised question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no where near a professional in shaders but I'm currently studying OpenGL and I know a couple things. I will try my best to help by answering the questions I do know about.

> What is uniform sampler2D texture? Is that only in the fragment shader? Does it need a texture passed in or does it use a default texture?

To be able to work on generated textures, the fragment shader needs a way to access that texture's object.
GLSL has a built-in data type that does exactly that and that would be the `sampler`. The sampler postfix defines what type the texture object is expected to be of, for example: `sampler2D`.
(There's also `sampler1D` and `sampler3D` but that's totally irrelevant).

To answer some of the questions I provide a simple example:

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;

out vec3 ourColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(ourColor, 1.0f);
}
```

> Sometimes I see fragment shaders which write "in vec2 some_var" and state that its passed in from the vertex shader but then I don't see the vertex shader actually passing anything to the fragment shader? Is this normal?

To pass an output from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, you need to specify that the variable is an output by using the `out` keyword.
In the example above, `out vec3 ourColor;` is outputted from the vertex shader to the fragment shader.

Now on the other hand, in order to accept inputs, the fragment shader needs to expect it, to specify that the fragment shader will be receiving input from the vertex shader, we use the `in` keyword.
In the example above, that would be `in vec3 ourColor;`.

To summarize, the `out` keyword is used to specify that some variable is an output and the `in` keyword specifies that a certain variable type is an expected input. This works because the specified `out` and `in` variables have matching types which is `vec3`.

One thing to note is that the vertex shader **should** receive an input so it has something to work on, otherwise it won't be able to do anything. That input is in form of vertex data.
On the other hand, fragment shaders are also **required** to output a `vec4` colour output variable.

For the vertex shader shown above, these would be:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
```

For the fragment shader shown above, this would be:

```
out vec4 FragColor;
```

**EDIT:**

To follow up on your revised question:

To put it simply, Uniforms are another way to send data to shaders.
It is important to note that uniforms are **global** meaning that they are accessible by all shaders at any point.

> is the code I provided a vertex shader or a fragment shader? Because it wants an in vec2?

The first observation we could make in the shader code you've provided to determine which type of shader this is, is that the shader outputs a vec4, which is the required output by the fragment shader, but this isn't concrete evidence that this is a fragment shader.

To be able to better identify which shader you're currently looking at, it is important to have an idea about the role of each shader.

Put simply, the vertex shader also allows us to do stuff with the attributes of the vertices it receives as input, such as the position.

The fragment shader's responsibility is basically to calculate the final colour of pixels that are in between the vertices.

In the shader code you've provided in the question, we can determine that the operations applied are more related to calculating the final colour and outputting it using `out vec4 color;`, which is the what the fragment shader is responsible of.

> In the code v_tex is a vec2 does that mean the vertex shader is passing in a vec2 to this fragment shader? What exactly is v_tex?

Yes, this means that the fragment shader is expecting an input of the type `vec2`. As stated above in the answer, to accept an input from the vertex shader, we need to specify that a certain variable is expecting a value of a certain type (`vec2`) from the vertex shader using the `in` keyword.
In the vertex shader, there's a variable of type `vec2` that has the `out` keyword and it matches the type of `v_tex` which is `vec2`.

`v_tex` is a `vec2` which means that it can hold 2 floats.
I believe it represents the texture coordinates for the current pixel.

As for it's role in the code you've provided, as far as I can understand, `center` is being subtracted from `v_tex` and then normalized, then the result is scaled by `u_amount` which should represent the displacement amount.

The result of this operation is a normalized `vec2` that is scaled by `u_amount`. It is based on the difference between the current pixel coordinates and the centre of the texture.

To actually apply this displacement effect, we need to set the colour of the current pixel.

The `color = texture(u_texture, v_tex - displacement)` operation samples the texture `u_texture` at the texture coordinates `v_tex - displacement`.

In simpler words, what this does is that it gets the colour of the pixel that is at the `v_tex - displacement` coordinate of the `u_texture` texture and assigns it to the colour of the current pixel (which is the pixel at the `v_tex` coordinates).

The final colour is then outputted.

I don't know what the exact result of this shader output looks like but I hope that I was able to at least give you an idea about what this is doing.

If you'd like to understand more about shaders, I highly, **highly**, recommend reading the "Shaders" section in the "Getting Started" chapter of the [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com) book.

Link to the "Shaders" section: [Shaders Section](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation so is the code I provided a vertex shader or a fragment shader? Because it wants an in vec2?

Comment: Check edited answer! I hope I was able to help!

Comment: Thank you! I think I get it

Comment: I edited the answer and added more explanation if you're still looking for it :)
Also, if you think this helped, please mark it as the answer :)